# How I get color stops on a gradient Shape? VBA

Tags: vba, excel

How I get color stops on a shape? 
I'm creating a tree flow chart, and I want to give them a gradient and I also want to change the gradient by percentage, so I want that one node is with 50% for the both color stops.

So the code that I have until now for the give a gradient pattern is:

```
        QNode.Shapes(1).Fill.TwoColorGradient msoGradientVertical, 1
```

I was trying something like:

```
QNode.Shapes(1).Fill.Interior.Gradient.ColorStops.Add(0.66)
```

Not working...

Specification:
Should work on 2003

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
        With QNode.Shapes(1).Fill
            .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
            .TwoColorGradient msoGradientVertical, 1
            .GradientStops(2).Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
            .GradientStops(2).Position = 0.66               
        End With
```

I just have to use GradietStops =D with the position that I want, in that case, I just want two positions, so gradientStops(1) and gradientStops(2), but you also can add more positions.

```
      .GradientStops.Insert RGB(0, 0, 0), 0.66
```