# Change the fill colour of a font to a gradient

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to use Word VBA to create a custom font gradient fill to change a specific text block to a 'half and half' colour pattern. See the image below.

[image]

The two circles on the right (they're both text elements) are currently being filled using VBA to a single solid colour. What I'd like to be able to do is create the pattern in the left circle. This pattern can be quite easily created using the gradients section of the font format window.

[image]

The `FillFormat` methods `OneColorGradient`, `TwoColorGradient` and `PresetGradient` don't seem to have the available options to add gradient stops with specific properties for font fills.

If this is not technically possible, I'm very much open to alternative suggestions.

Answer (score -1):

You should find the options you need if you use the VBA object Browser with Word as the library you are searching.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of the object browser. Font.Fill doesn't support the GradientStops method.

Comment: This should give you a hint https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44564687/how-i-get-color-stops-on-a-gradient-shape-vba.  However, when I try to use the GradientStops in Word I get errors.